# move an element with jquery with accelerated speed

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

moving an object is quiet simple. imagine this:

```
 $("#myelement").animate({left:'+=200'},2000);
```

the problem is that I want my element to start moving slowly and speed up continuously along the way.

does anyone have a clue how to do this?

Comment: you mean, like [easing](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)?

Comment: actually i'm not familiar with easing. but I mean however if it floats my boat its enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

You need to use the jQuery easing plugin, and use an EASE IN option. I recommend 'easeInExpo' but you can see all the options here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/easing.html

If all you need is easing, I think jQuery ui (which has the plugin built in) is overkill. You can just use the plugin in a lean form.

It would look something like this:

```
$("#myelement").animate({left:'+=200'},2000, 'easeInExpo');
```

You may also like 'easeInCubic'

Answer (score 0):

The [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function has an easing option. You can load a pre-defined one or work out your own to achieve exactly the affect that you want.

[These](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/) are some that are pre-built that are pretty good that I use.